# Ubuntu Installation : Ubuntu does not show up

Tags: startup

I had installed Ubuntu not long ago, when it prompted me to restart to use Ubuntu, it restarted and went straight to Windows. It did not show any sign of Ubuntu. The version of Ubuntu i installed is 16.04 LTS. I am in UEFI and my bios is v1.04.

Comment: Do you have Windows 10, and if so, did you update it to the anniversary update?

Comment: @Patrick Negus manually installing ubuntu on win anniversary update DOES NOT wipe ubuntu

Comment: @ubuntuttttuuuuu how did u install it? In UEFI or in LEFACY? which mode is your windows in? Check default boot settings in bios menu!  which is your machine model? ubuntu version? Provide all this details and edit the question

Comment: @minigeek No, the anniversary update does not wipe Ubuntu. However, it does blow up grub.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Fastboot option in windows 10 under Settings>Power options> and try to reinstall grub with the ubuntu disc or USB you used to install it.

Comment: never mind i did it

Comment: this did not work... I used boot repair and got a security boot failure. after that a text came up and said windows boot manager is not the first boot option. than it came back to windows. I tried using the bios menu to change the boot order, but when I rebooted I got the same error. please help